# Issue with file versioning with python

Tags: python, path, versioning

I did a Python application which needs to open an excel file to find data inside.

Every time this excel file has a new version its name is also changed like `test_V1.2.xlsx` to `test_V1.3.xlsx` so my path becomes incorrect.

I have no idea how to correct this dynamically, is it possible to point on test_V like with a regular expression?

my path looks like this :

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\300231823\Desktop\GUI\simplenew4_V1.**1**.xls')

When someone change the file version to simplenew4_V1.**2**.xls my variable WB do not point on my excel file and my program do not works

Comment: We will need more code to help you here. But perhaps you can split the filename by `_` and remove the extension. Then you'll have the version (like `"V1.2"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prefix is always the same you can use `os.listdir()` to get what is in the folder.

here's code:

```
import os

prefix = "test_V"
folder_path = r"C:\Users\300231823\Desktop\GUI"

for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if prefix in file:
        excel_file = os.path.join(folder_path, file)

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(excel_file)
```

Comment: It'll work if there's only one version at the time you run it.

Comment: Yes I confirm, this is exactly what I was looking for. You rocks !

Comment: Hello Arthur, I have permission issue using this method, here the code I wrote (after your suggestion :root=Tk()
root.title('24x99')
root.geometry("630x300")

wb=Workbook()
prefix = "Spec varmus Malus"
filepath=r"\\nas2-pp.ppp.com\users\_BPM\Aba\5 - Malus\Proc"

for file in os.listdir(filepath):
    if prefix in file:
        excel_file = os.path.join(filepath, file)

wb=load_workbook(excel_file)
sheet = wb['Spec']